# Error - Access to the path is denied - Network Share

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I'm trying to access file in network share and i get this exception.
this is windows service.

```
Error In function Handle_Files(): System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\tempserver\public\' is denied.
```

and i dont have app.config file.

thanks.

Comment: Your service doesn't have access to that network location.

Comment: You need to assure the user the service runs under has appropriate permissions. What does app.config have to do with that?

Comment: how can i give access to my service?

and app.config can have <identity/> tag, buy i don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Computer Management application.  Open the "Services and Applications\Services" node (or whatever it's called in your version of windows).  Find your service in the list of services.  Right-click on your service and select the "Properties" option from the context menu.  In the properties dialog window, open the "Log On" tab.  This is where you can view and modify the user account under which your service runs.  You need to either give sharing access to that network share to that user, or you need to change the service's log on account to a user that already has access to that network share.